# How To Prevent Duplicate Email Addresses on a User Registration Form?

Tags: c#, validation

I want to prevent duplicate email addresses during registration.  How would I go about validating the text box on entry so that the same email address won't be accepted twice?

Comment: Where's the "Be rude to a new user" badge?  We'd be handing a lot of them out these days.  Cut the person a little slack.  English is probably not his first language and its his first time here.  At least he bothered to sign up.

Comment: Totally agree with @tvanfosson, perhaps they'd be better off asking the question on Experts-Exchange...?

Comment: +1 for tvanfosson for pointing to an real big stack overflow issue.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Well in my opinion, it's not a question of being new, or even about first languages.  It's about being bothered to structure your question so you are giving the answerers the information they need to help you.  1) People are kindly sharing their knowledge 2) They freely giving their time to write a coherent answer. 3) Lazy questions do not make for a good archive of knowledge.  If the poster cannot invest the time to properly describe their problem, then why should others invest their time to help?

Comment: Have you considered the OP did the best they could? If you ever traveled to a country where the language wasn't your first, and you needed help bad but everyone refused to help you because you couldn't say the sentences right, would you like that?

Comment: @Sosh: I think that many times, these questions are so bad because the OP cannot start with a good question in his language and then translate into English. For all we know, he might have been able to write a very good question in his own language.

Comment: @Gman - Well, As I said, I don't beleive its a language thing.  Actually I live in a country where the langauge isn't my first.

Comment: @Sosh: I don't know why, but we get some questions from people whose English is _really_ bad. Maybe there's a cultural or economic thing where most non-native English speakers would be embarrassed if their English was that bad, but that embarrassment is a secondary consideration to these users. There is significant overlap between the set of users with very bad English and the set that will not return to clarify a question.

Answer (score 17):

I think is is probably most appropriate handled as a uniqueness constraint (or unique index) on that column in the database.  This will ensure the integrity of the database and you can check the error message to determine whether the failed insert/update was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways.

Way 1: Dynamically query the database and display a message such as, "This email address already is in the server, please choose another" You'd be doing the check each time the user typed into the text box.

Way 2: Have a two-phase registration where on submittal of the information, you have a validation routine execute to check that all information is acceptable - in your case, it would be to check for duplication of email addresses.

I recommend the second way I put up - it reduces server load.

Answer (score 0):

That code would not be entered in/on a text box rather when the forms is submitted you would check if it was used already. Also if you want to do it otherwise (while the user is typing) you can use ajax to help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing both the unique index on the database to protect data integrity, but also you should have validations on submit or through some ajax call that checks the email address as well.